# When using the Access SendObject command, how can I specify 2 outputformat options (excel & pdf)?

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007

I am using the SendObject command in Access 2007 and I  can specify either an excel file or a PDF file as the outputformat for sending my Access object but I was wondering if there is a way that I can specify the command to attach both an Excel and a PDF version instead of either or?

For Example:

```
DoCmd.SendObject acSendForm, formName, acFormatXLSX, , , , "test", "See attached", True
```

in the above code, I am attaching an excel file. I can use acFormatPDF instead to send a PDF file but is there a way I can send both in the same email? Any ideas or workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cannot be done in a single command.

You must do SendObject twice.

Comment: So that means I need to send 2 separate emails? acFormatXLSX sends the data in my form in excel format and acFormatPDF sends a screen shot of the form in PDF format. Is there a way to send both in same email?

Comment: No.  If you use DoCmd.SendObject you must send two separate emails.  You could use some other process to generate the spreadsheet and PDF files, then manually attach them to a new email, however that discussion is way beyond the scope of this site.